# Why is $1+\cos(\theta)=2\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Why is $1+\cos(\theta)=2\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$?

Where this comes from? I don't get it.

From $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$?? I search everything but I really don't find that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addition formula: 
$\cos(2z)=\cos^2 z - \sin^2 z = \cos^2 -(1-\cos^2 z) = 2 \cos^2 z - 1.$ Now use $z=\theta /2$

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos(2 \theta) = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta = 2 \cos^2 \theta - 1$$
Then put $$x = 2 \theta$$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Hint**: Use the Law of Cosines on an isosceles triangle whose equal sides are $1$ to find $\cos\theta$. Then use this result to derive.
$$1+\cos\theta=2\cos^2(\theta/2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Two basic formulas of trigonometry:
\begin{gather}
\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1\\[6px]
\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta
\end{gather}

In the second formula, set $\alpha=\beta=\theta/2$: then
\begin{align}
\cos\theta&=
\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-
\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\\[6px]
&=
\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\\[6px]
&=
\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-1+\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}\\[6px]
&=
2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-1
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Use:   $\displaystyle \quad \cos \theta=\cos \left (2\cdot\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\cdots$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=1+\cos z-2 \cos^2 \dfrac{z}{2}$. Then 
$$
f'(z)=-\sin z+2 \cos \dfrac{z}{2}\sin \dfrac{z}{2}=-\sin z + \sin z=0. 
$$
Thus $f(z)$ is a constant for any $z.$ For example $f(z)=f(0)=1+1-2=0.$ $f(z)=0$  follows that $$1+\cos z=2 \cos^2 \dfrac{z}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition ($i$ is the complex unit),
$$ \cos \theta =\frac{e^{i \theta}+e^{-i \theta}}{2}$$
Now expand the RHS:
$$ 2\cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2}=2\left(\frac{e^{i \theta/2}+e^{-i \theta/2}}{2}\right)^2=2\cdot\frac{e^{i \theta}+2+e^{-i \theta}}{4}=1+\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}=1+\cos\theta$$