# Can you prove this? $2+2\cos(x-y)=4\cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove the following

$$2+2\cos(x-y)=4\cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$

Comment: @Tushar Are you aware of the identity $\cos (2 A) =2 \cos^2 (A) - 1$ for some angle $A$?

Comment: @Kevin sorry but i don't know

Comment: I believe this identity, if used correctly, should help you. Write $2A=x-y$ and rearrange the identity so that the square of the cosine is only on the right hand side of the equals sign

Comment: Also, don't get disheartened at the down votes to this question.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks , I got the solution.

Comment: If you can type your efforts down in an edit to your question, using the following tutorial help, it's likely you'll garner more attention. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Excellent, keep coming back to ask some more questions, the more you use the site the more used you will get to asking questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is $1+\cos(\theta)=2\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407975/why-is-1-cos-theta-2-cos2-frac-theta2)

Answer (score 2):

You have to prove:

$1+ \cos(t)=2\cos^2(t/2).$

To this end use

$\cos(t)= \cos(t/2+t/2)= \cos^2(t/2)-\sin^2(t/2)$

and

$\cos^2 (t/2)+ \sin^2(t/2)=1.$

Comment: You mistyped the sign in double angle formula

Comment: ?? we have $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a) \cos(b)- \sin(a) \sin(b).$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $\cos (2x)=2\cdot\cos^2 x -1$, and $x-y=2\cdot\dfrac {x-y}2$.

Comment: Please only make the edits you need, and don't remove parts of the answer you think are unnecessary. This question could also be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\begin{align}\bigl(1+ \cos(t)-2\cos^2(t/2)\bigr)'&=-\sin(t)-4\cos(t/2)(-\sin(t/2))\cdot\frac12\\
&=-2\sin(t/2)\cos(t/2)+2\cos(t/2)\sin(t/2)\\
&=0,
\end{align}$$
hence $1+ \cos(t)-2\cos^2(t/2)$ is constant. Now plug in $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=\dfrac{x-y}{2}$,

$\cos \left(2t\right)=2\cos^2t-1 \\4\cos^2t=2\cos\left(2t\right)+2\\4\cos^2\left(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right)=2\cos\left(x-y\right)+2$